# In SOQL, Difference between passing list of id or List of sObject in WHERE IN clause

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, salesforce1-app

```
 List<Account> accountList = [SELECT Id 
                              FROM Account 
                              WHERE BillingCity='Pune'];

 List<Id> accountIds = new List<Id>();

 for(account accountRecord : accountList){
        accountIds.add(accountRecord.id);
 }
 /* Line 1 */
 List<Opportunity> opportunityList1 = [SELECT Id, Amount 
                                       FROM Opportunity 
                                       WHERE accountId IN: accountIds];

 /* Line 2 */
 List<Opportunity> opportunityList2 = [SELECT Id, Amount 
                                       FROM Opportunity 
                                       WHERE accountId IN:accountList ];
```

Are the line both line are the same ?
If any difference, what are the difference(s)?

Any limitation in the above query ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably a wash.

If your number of parents is very large (~49k records), using `Set<Id>` is marginally (~16%) faster. For me, the `List<SObject>` merge query took on average `.208s` and the `Set<Id>` merge query took on average `.179s`. That does affect the number of queries you could run in a transaction, but for a single query doesn't save you much.

If the number of parents is small, it seems like `List<SObject>` may actually be faster, clocking in at `3.5ms`, as opposed to `Set<Id>` at `4.1ms` for a differential of 17%.

I timed the query as demonstrated below, swapping `100` for `49000` and `parents` for `parentIds` as needed to generate the above data. I ran 5 trials with each configuration so the sample size is not huge.

```
List<Account> parents = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 49000];
Set<Id> parentIds = Pluck.ids(parents);

Long start = Datetime.now().getTime();
for (Integer i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    List<Opportunity> records = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId = :parentIds];
system.debug(Datetime.now().getTime() - start);
```

My child table was pretty empty, you could probably rerun this analysis with a heavily used child table and get completely different results.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference in both statement except using an extra variable.

If you need only Account id for other purpose then store the Account Ids in list/set for further use.

if you don't need then I suggest 2nd option is optimal one

Direct query with list of sobject.

```
 List<Opportunity> opportunityList2 = [SELECT Id, Amount 
                                       FROM Opportunity 
                                       WHERE accountId IN: accountList ];
```

Answer (score -2):

The second line will give you a following error,

```
COMPILE ERROR: Invalid bind expression type of Account for Id field of SObject Opportunity
```

In second line, compiler expects to have Id type for binding where as you have given the list type for binding.

Comment: Run exactly the code posted in execute anonymous and you will find that the error you have posted does not occur.

Comment: Could someone please explain why does it work, intuitively  I would have said that it would generate an error.

Comment: If we pass list it works fine. Opportunity Query will fetch exactly id from the parentList.